# Array Creation Method with a 'name' Parameter: Scope Error

Tags: java, arrays, methods, scope

I'm creating some helper methods for a class project. One of the methods I wanted to create was a simple create an array of type int, called 'name', of 'size' size. The problem arises in the body of the method where I try to use the 'name' parameter to create the array.

```
public int[] createArray(String name, int size){

    int[] name = new int[size];

}
```

In addition to getting a "Variable 'name' is already defined in the scope." error, I think the issue is that I can't use a variable in the construction of an array. If that's the case, should I not be using 'String name' as a parameter here? Is there some sort of parse/conversion I can do? Conclusively, what do I have to use/do to pass a parameter from the method call into "int[] _____ = new int[size];"?

I'll probably just make the 2 arrays I need normally in the main method, but I wanted to learn what I was doing wrong.

Best,

Corey

Comment: You can't choose your variable names based on the value of a string.

Answer (score 2):

Rename you variable `name` in

```
int[] name = new int[size];
```

to

```
int[] otherName = new int[size];
```

and it should work fine. Since there is another variable with the same name in the scope because of `String name` used as your argument to the method.

Also in case you want to use the parameter to actually name your array variable, then you would probably be trying to modify the source code during its runtime, which you can't. That said, the variable `String name` doesn't seem useful in the method anymore.

Comment: I did indeed want to use the parameter to name the array variable, but now I know why I cant. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @CoreyJones Welcome :) If that helps do mark it as an answer so that it helps people in future as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is impossible (unless you resort to "reflection" which I wouldn't recommend to a relative beginner).

You want to create an array variable with a name that you want to decide at runtime. You want to do something like

```
int[] array1;
int[] array2;
createArray("array1", 17);
createArray("array2", 25);
```

The variable names `array1` and `array2` exist at compile time. When the program runs, they are no longer available (to normal Java code). The `"array1"` and `"array2"` parameters that you want to pass to the `createArray()` method are strings, and the Java runtime will not associate the characters in these strings with the array variables.

The Java way for the thing you tried to achieve is:

```
int[] array1 = createArray(17);
int[] array2 = createArray(25);
private int[] createArray(int size) {
    return new int[size];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't have an understanding of the variable names and what happens at compile time like how you explained it. I appreciate the solution as well.